# Where can I find more information about Nested Line Items?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm looking into adding multiple products at once as a bundle to the Shopping Cart. The main goals are that you can remove the whole bundle in the cart with all the products, but you can also see the products as a bundle in the order administration.

To accomplish this I'm looking for more information about nested line items. I found this in the documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/use-nested-line-items. But I'm looking for more information, like code-wise (PHP).

Who can help me into the right direction?

Comment: Is this the way to implement it? If so, then yes I can work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example on how to set line items as the children of another line item.

```php
private CartService $cartService;

private CartPersister $cartPersister;

public function addNestedLineItems(string $containerLineItemId, SalesChannelContext $context): void
{
    $containerLineItem = $this->getLineItem($containerLineItemId);

    // hard-coded ids for the sake of this example
    $nestedLineItems = new LineItemCollection([
        $this->getLineItem('88f1537e73f14fd09f6e7e607a32b722'),
        $this->getLineItem('19e1691f7c35435291ef80fe576434c2'),
    ]);
    
    $containerLineItem->setChildren($nestedLineItems);

    $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($context->getToken(), $context);
    $cart->add($containerLineItem);
    
    $this->cartPersister->save($cart, $context);
}

private function getLineItem(string $productId): LineItem
{
    $item = new LineItem($productId, LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE, $productId, 1);
    $item->setGood(true);
    $item->setRemovable(true);
    $item->setStackable(true);

    return $item;
}
```

The next time around the cart is then loaded and processed, e.g. the next request, the line items should appear as a subset of items under the container line item in the cart.

Comment: I'm sending multiple products to a controller function. If I dump $requestDataBag->get('lineItems') I can see all the products. How can I bundle them to nested LineItems?